# font not working on index page in firefox

Tags: css, .htaccess, firefox, fonts, font-awesome

I'm using Helvetica Neue Light and Fontawesome on this webpage. The typefaces work fine on Chrome and Safari and on the INDEX page in Firefox, but on all the other pages in Firefox they don't work.

Here's my @font-face code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light';
    src: url('HelveticaNeue-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('HelveticaNeue-Light.woff') format('woff'), 
         url('HelveticaNeue-Light.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('HelveticaNeue-Light.svg#HelveticaNeue-Light') format('svg');
}
```

I tried inserting this code in my .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I eventually tried the following, and THIS worked:

1. Type 'about:config' in the address bar;
2. Search for 'security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy' and set it to false.

However, is there any way to make the fonts show up without having to tamper with the settings in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

I always had issues with font rendering in Firefox. Try with a complete URL (without www) for your files, it worked for me a few months ago.:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Light';
src: url('http://yourwebsite.com/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.eot') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('http://yourwebsite.com/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.woff') format('woff'), 
     url('http://yourwebsite.com/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('http://yourwebsite.com/fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.svg#HelveticaNeue-Light') format('svg');}
```